# При изменении шрифта у label, элемент UILabel съезжает на лево

Tags: ios, swift

Вот констрейны из Сториборда:

[image: Вот констрейны из Сториборда]

Вот при стандартном шрифте: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В приложении есть пункт настройки шрифта, от туда юзер может увеличить шрифт, затем я загоняю это в `UserDefault` и по ключу получаю шрифт. После изменении шрифта мой `UILabel` съезжает, фишка в том что не сам текст съезжает, а весь объект `UILabel`.

Вот пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот иерархия вьюшек:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

меняю шрифт тут:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    imageHeight = myImage.frame.height

    let sizeFontSetting = UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "slideValue")
    if sizeFontSetting != 0 && sizeFontSetting != 1 {
        settingFontSizeForLabels()
    }
}

func settingFontSizeForLabels(){                
    titleLabel.font = UIFont().setSize(size: 20, fontName: "SFUIDisplay-Regular")
    titleLabel.sizeToFit()

    headerLabel.font = UIFont().setSize(size: 16, fontName: "SFUIDisplay-Medium")
    headerLabel.sizeToFit()

    descr.font = UIFont().setSize(size: 15, fontName: "SFUIDisplay-Light")
    descr.sizeToFit()
}
```

это Расширение для `UIFont`

```
    extension UIFont {
    func setSize(size: CGFloat, fontName: String) -> UIFont?{
        let sizeFontSetting = UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "slideValue")        
        return UIFont(name: fontName, size: (CGFloat(sizeFontSetting) * size))
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте задать UILabel цвет фона, это поможет найти проблему

Comment: Я пробовал, сам uilabel смещается в лево.

Comment: Можете показать левую панель (иерархию View)?

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk обновил вопрос.  Добавил иерархию

Comment: Действительно, немного странно. Сначала я подумал что проблемы с View, Main View или My Scroll View, но тогда бы сдвинулись и остальные элементы.

Comment: Покажи код, где меняешь размер шрифта плиз. И в какой процедуре меняешь шрифт?

Comment: @VasiliiMuravev обновил вопрос.

Comment: Когда меняешь шрифт непосредственно в Storyboard, такого безобразия не происходит?

Comment: @VasiliiMuravev, не-а

Comment: Попробуй подкрасить superview для этого label'а и посмотри меняется ли оно. Возможно, съезжает как раз оно.

Comment: @VasiliiMuravev видишь сверху дату ? У title и date один супер вью, так что если бы супер вью съезжала то и дата съезжала

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62393/discussion-between-vasilii-muravev-and--).

Comment: Попробуйте убрать sizeToFit() и посмотрите, сохранится ли проблема

Comment: @VitaliEller просто магия, убрал sizeToFit() работает.

Comment: Добавил как ответ, рад что помогло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите `sizeToFit()`. Эта функция сжимает лейбл до размеров текста, поэтому ваш лейбл смещается, так как его фрейм изменяется.